# Chrome extension: How to insert or paste text into a tweet

Tags: google-chrome-extension, insert

driving me nuts.. backstory.. I enter a LOT of contests on twitter, and find myself repeating common tasks of copy/pasting profile links and tagging friends. :)

So i figured, and extension might make this easier!

manifest:

```
{
   "name": "Context Menus Sample (with Event Page)", 
  "description": "Shows some of the features of the Context Menus API using an event page",
  "version": "0.7",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs", "clipboardWrite", "clipboardRead" ],
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

sample.js

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == 'h_profile') { 
        // here is where it needs to put the text   

     }

};

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

  // Set up context menu tree at install time.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "HELLCASE", "contexts":["editable"], "id": "hellcase"});
    chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "PROFILE", "contexts":["editable"], "parentId": "hellcase", "id": "h_profile"});

});
```

i can get it to trigger, like an alert on clicking.. but no matter what i try i cant get it to insert text into the focused textarea (div) on twitter
i think it could be because its just a div and not an actual element like a textarea...
seems like it should be easy, yet it wont work! lol

any ideas?

UPDATE: it seems I needed a few more things - i dont know if they were all needed but it now works!

```
{
  "name": "TwitterHelper",
  "description": "Helps to make entering contests easier!",
  "version": "0.5",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus","tabs","activeTab"],
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["myscript.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

myscript.js

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == 'h_profile') { 
            SendText('profile');
     }

};

function SendText(strText){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: 'var temp = document.activeElement.innerHTML; document.activeElement.innerHTML=temp + "' + strText + '";'
          });
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

  // Set up context menu tree at install time.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "HELLCASE", "contexts":["editable"], "id": "hellcase"});
    chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "PROFILE", "contexts":["editable"], "parentId": "hellcase", "id": "h_profile"});

});
```

Comment: You need a content script where you can use document.execCommand with `insertText` parameter.

Comment: im pretty sure thats one that I have tried, but since the div has no name, i need to just insert at the focus? or would that be the same thing? maybe i was closer than I thought...

Comment: The execCommand does not work with twitter. It leads to issues like backsapce not working